# In WordPress, how do you have a hyphenated and non-hyphenated slug lead to the same page?

Tags: url, hyperlink, permalinks, slug

On WordPress, how do I adjust the permalink or the slug values so that, say (using a fictitious site path), plants.com/floweringdogwood and plants.com/flowering-dogwood will each land on plants.com/flowering-dogwood? Is this possible? For instance, if I meet someone and want them to check out this type of tree, and I tell them verbally to check out "plants.com slash flowering dogwood", is it possible if they type in "plants.com/floweringdogwoods" for it to still land "plants.com/flowering-dogwoods"?

I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not sure if this is even possible or not. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Try [wordpress.se].